# Rat in a Maze involving Two Rats Backtracking

Tags: matrix, graph, backtracking

Rat in a Maze is a backtracking problem where given an NxN matrix, you have to get the solution on how to find a path from the source to the destination cell. Having one rat is a bit easier but having two rats in a problem is quite difficult. They should move simultaneously in each find of another cell and they should not be on adjacent cells. I know it is a backtracking problem but I'm kinda lost on how should I do it. The rats can move up, left, right, down and diagonally too but cannot go in an obstacle/landmine in the matrix. How should the pseudocode be?